# Redirecting old website to Magento website

Tags: magento-1.8, url, 301-redirect

I already finished my Magento website, now I need to redirect all old website urls to Magento url pages.

I already did "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to "Yes (301 Moved permanently)".

By the way the old website and Magento "new website" are in the same root directory, I just renamed the old index.html to indexold.html for the old website.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to either add redirects in your admin system (Catalog | URL Rewrite Management) or do it in a .htacess.  It probably depends how many pages you need to redirect and also if your old URLs had any pattern against them - that might make RegEx an easier way to go.

There seem to be a number of plugins that might let you monitor 404s so that you can implement redirects - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=404+manager&pl=0

Comment: Thanks Douglas, does it matter if the old site is not Magento site

Comment: No, not at all, you'll be redirecting URLs. As long as you know the URLs, you're golden!

Comment: I tried with (Catalog | URL Rewrite Management) I wrote the old and new url but it doesn't redirect the old one

Comment: Could you post an example?  Have you looked over http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-url-rewrites and https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index ?

Comment: this is old url:www.cabas-durables.fr/contents/fr/d85_sac_kraft_fenetre.html, and this is new url: www.cabas-durables.fr/sacs-bouteilles/sacs-papier-a-fenetre-transparente

Comment: So, you have the old AND the new site running alongside each other? In which case, you need to add the redirect to the OLD site, as it's still responding to the requests :)

Comment: can you tell me how I can do that

Comment: Depends what your old system runs on.  Probably best to look up the documentation for that.